# JavaScript ES6, how to "save" properties from an object into a new one, without repeating the keys?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a new object `savedStyle`, with key/values from the `style` object, without repeating the object keys:

```js
const style = getComputedStyle(document.body);

const savedStyle = {
  position: style.position, // the repetition
};
```

Why? I think it's not ideal, a small typo like `psition` could lead to a broken code:

```
Object.assign(document.body, savedStyle);
```

Is there any way to save multiple values, with the same key of the original object?

**EDIT**: verbose way:

```js
const { position } = style;
const savedStyle = { 
  position,
};
```

Comment: Put all the desired keys in an array and iterate it with forEach e.g. `['position','top'].forEach(k => savedStyle[k] = style[k])`?

Comment: Sure @Nick, but I was looking for a more elegant solution, thanks!

Comment: you want all keys/values from style?

Comment: What's wrong with `const savedStyle = style;`

Comment: `verbose way` would be the way I'd do it - either that or create a helper function that may be a little verbose but simple to use

Comment: @Evert because i don't want all the pairs.

Comment: @gremo `Object.keys(style).forEach` and `savedStyle[key] = style[key]`. not works with Symbol properties

Comment: @gremo important detail! For loop or `filter` seems like the way to go.

Comment: I think there's a [proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements) which would allow you to do `const savedStyle = {style.position}` as shorthand for `const savedStyle = {position: style.position}` which is what you could do now